# HTML5 App should open website. How I can set the background color?

Tags: html

I wrote a very simple HTML app. The app opens a little loading animation and redirects to a website. Im tested this on my windows phone. The background color should be black. It is black   at the start, but when I click on something and the IE loads the page the background is white...
How I can set the background color of the IE loading?

My Html app code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Die Witze App</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://witze.reddoit.de/" /> 
        <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:black">
    <!--<p id="ladetext">Die Witze App<p>-->

    <div class=ladeanimation>
        <div class="windows8">
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_1">
        <div class="wInnerBall">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_2">
        <div class="wInnerBall">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_3">
        <div class="wInnerBall">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_4">
        <div class="wInnerBall">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wBall" id="wBall_5">
        <div class="wInnerBall">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>




    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the CSS file, make sure you don't have any background properties in any class or ID selector.

If you dont have any then try adding  `background-color: #000000;` to the ladeanimation class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! But I mean: When you click on a link or something on thsi website/app the screen is white for the loading time on my windows phone. In chrome on my pc ... there is no white loading page. but a phone is slower and theres a white loading screen. I just want to make this black

Comment: Is it only on your windows phone? Did you try IE on desktop? perhaps it could be the mobile browser that shows a blank white screen when redirecting

Comment: Yes its only on my windows phone, because when the IE loads the page it is some seconds blank ans thats the problem. I havent tested it yet on the iphone in the safari browser.